# Get Rid of a QAction.trigger.connect in pyside2

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I have the following function to bind my dynamically generated Actions in the ToolBar with a name passing function:

```
def bind_action(self, action, name):
    '''bind an Action to the ToolBar'''
    action.triggered.connect(lambda: self._fct.get_name(name))
```

Now the user may change the name at runtime. And I call the function a second time to bind the new name. If the QAction is triggered now, I have the problem that both triggers are sent. Is it possible to delete the first connect again? I found a workaround (I check if the name is in a list), but I want to have it neater.

As private feedback I got this question recommended: stackoverflow.com/questions/45090982/… It is the exactly opposite problem. There, a user want to know how he can add a second parameter, my Question is: **How can I get rid of the first triggered.connect()?**

Comment: Use `action.triggered.disconnect()`.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro. this solved my problem!